# Load an add-on HTML page on Firefox startup

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I have made a plugin using the addon SDK. The plugin adds a button to the nav-bar, and when it is clicked it opens a new tab with some data from an internal indexeddb using code similar to this:

```
// main.js
tabs.open({
  url: self.data.url('index.html'),
  onReady: runScript
});

function runScript(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: [
      self.data.url("script.js")]
  });
}
```

Everything works fine, except for the scenario where the user quits Firefox and opens it again, that tab will be restored, but it will contain nothing because it hasn't been triggered by the addon button click. This is because the scripts on the page are loaded through the `runScript` function in `main.js`, which is not executed when the HTML file is loaded on a restart.

How can I get this tab to have the same behavior on page startup than on button clicking?

Comment: What URL is shown for the restored tab?

Comment: resource://jid1-gzlhtgbcb5hzka-at-jetpack/myextension/data/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to reload the tab:

```
exports.main = function(options) {
  if(options.reason==='startup') for (var i=tabs.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    var tab = tabs[i];
    if (tab.url!==self.data.url('index.html')) continue;
    tab.once('ready', runScript.bind(null, tab));
    tab.reload();
    /* If it can't reload the tab,
    use tab.url = self.data.url('index.html'); */
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: My pleasure. I've edited the answer (changed `tab.on` to `tab.once` so that `runScript` is only called once. Otherwise your script would be injected into every page you navigate to in that tab until you close it.

Answer (score -1):

This a bug I had reported it awhile ago on bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=973326#c2)

I added your topic as an example.

So what you have to do for now, is onReady, you have to turn you body into html datauri and set the location of the tab to this contents.

For example on ready:

```
var htmlDataUri = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(document.documentElement.innerHTML);
//end make htmldatauri
document.location = htmlDataUri;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't see how this would help. `onReady` will never execute because this happens on the addon script side, which is not executed when the HTML page is loaded on startup.

Comment: I dont know sdk. Whatever event fires when that tab has finished loading your page, then run this code.

Comment: The reason it blanks out is when you make a new tab with addon sdk it opens about:blank and populates that with your html. if you want non-sdk version i can give you an example of that would you like to see? upload an xpi of your addon and i will give you a demo non-sdk